# Cannot query LDAP replica

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to setup a LDAP server with replica, but I'm having some problems.
I have 2 servers - ldap1.example.com (master) and ldap2.example.com (replica).
Running search query such as
`ldapsearch -D "cn=reader,dc=example,dc=com" -w  -h ldap1.example.com -b "dc=example,dc=com "uid=testuser"`

Returns the data as expected. However running the same query with `-h ldap2.example.com` ends with

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: uid=testuser
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

Even though the replication definitely works, because running `slapcat` on replica returns all the data.

My syncrepl.ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncrepl: rid=1
    provider=ldap://ldap1.example.com
    type=refreshAndPersist
    retry="30 10 600 10"
    interval=00:00:05:00
    searchbase=dc=example,dc=com
    scope=sub
    schemachecking=on
    binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
    credentials="supersecretpassword"
    starttls=yes
    tls_reqcert=allow
```

Comment: What is the configuration of `olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config` on your replica?

Comment: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config from the replica: https://pastebin.com/G0sK2Be7 you can see the syncrepl configuration there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ACL does not allow the dn you are binding with read access.

Currently:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
 by anonymous auth
 by * none
olcAccess: {1}to *
 by self write
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
 by * none
```

Suggested:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
 by anonymous auth
 by * none
olcAccess: {1}to *
 by self write
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
 by users read
 by * none
```